# Can I send a message to an IRC channel without joining it?

Tags: irc

Can I send a message to an IRC channel without joining it?

Are there usually any security restrictions set on production IRC servers to stop this?

Comment: Exactly. From what I recall, it is allowed by the protocol, but usually disabled on the servers.

Comment: @user1095108 I expect such situation. Is disabling sending message to non-joined canal standard option or server implementation specific? I don't deeply dig into RFC yet...

Comment: I've written an IRC client in Delphi sometime in the nineties and even then there were a plethora of `ircd` versions and many protocol extensions. You'll have to discover these, as you write your client. From what I see, `irc` is losing out to various chat programs and `skype`; it is seen as too hardcore for most of users nowadays :( I really wouldn't bother with implementing `irc` anymore, except if it is a small client and an educational endeavor. From my memory, yeah, all of them had this disabled by default.

Comment: @user1095108 thanks! It will be used by internal dev-team as it is possible to write simple parser/bot because of plain text protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From RFC 2811 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2811#section-4.2.4):

> 4.2.4 No Messages To Channel From Clients On The Outside
>
> When the channel flag 'n' is set, only channel members MAY send
> messages to the channel.
>
> ```
>  This flag only affects users.
> ```

I've never seen a channel that wasn't set to +n, however. (Although I haven't really looked.)

In summary: theoretically it is possible, but most servers are probably set to not allow it by default.